# Ajax OnSuccess no response

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-ajax

I have a java script function that is not being called when AJAX OnSuccess returns. There seems to be lack of documentation and examples, and therefore I am struggling to see where I am going Wrong.

Here's my view with JavaScript function which ATM is not alerting me that it is being called. Do I need to add logic to the controller?

```
    @model Models.customer
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OnSuccess() {
            alert('Success');
        }
    </script>

    <h2>Delete</h2>

    <h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Delete", "Customer", new AjaxOptions {OnSuccess="OnSuccess" }))
    {
       <fieldset>
         <legend>customer</legend>

         @Html.DisplayForModel()

       </fieldset>
       <p>
         <input type="submit" value="Delete"/> 
         @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", new { conName = ViewBag.connectionName }, null)
       </p>
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting some other options, like `HttpMethod = "POST"`, `OnFailure = "YourFailFunction"`, `InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace`, `UpdateTargetId = "YourTargetId"`?

Comment: What's the response from the server?  If it isn't a successful call your OnSuccess function will not get called...

Comment: Yes I have tried post, OnFailure.

Comment: the server does not error because i have exception handling therfore I presumed it was success. I will check what response I am getting from the server

Comment: @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Delete", "Customer", new AjaxOptions {    HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "alert('success');", OnFailure = "alert('fail');" }))  Still no response

Comment: server response from delete is 200 OK

Comment: Do you get any errors in the debugger console in your browser? (Press F12 and look for console)

Comment: I have the impression that you might need an `UpdateTargetId` on the `AjaxOptions`, but I'm not sure because the documentation is not very clear.

Comment: even using default constructor should return OnSuccess, stumped why it is not calling javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` included in your page as `Ajax` helpers require this to work.